# Is there any way to find auto save is completed in google drive docs api in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have created sample web application for access google drive APIs.

1. Enabled google drive documents APIs using my google account.
2. Downloaded credential.json file and included inside the project.
3. Uploaded one document to my google drive
4. Opened that file with editor in IFRAME.
5. Edited the file in iframe and its get auto saved.

Is there any way to find out the event or api call to check auto save is completed in google drive docs api in .NET?

Comment: There is a whole section in the google drive documentation for changes have you tried reading though it [Changes overview.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/change-overview)  You might also want to read though [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what questions are acceptable on stack.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*No pre-defined API function exists to automatically check when the auto-save of a native Google Drive file has completed.*

#### Workaround:

With some async code you can create a delegate function in C# to act as a callback which makes a return when the number of revisions to your iframed file has incremented.

Make an API call to retrieve the current number of file revisions

```c#
RevisionsResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Revisions.List();
// Use maximum page size to make sure to get all
listRequest.PageSize = 1000; 
listRequest.FileId = "<file-id>";

IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.Revision> revisions = listRequest.Execute()
```

Then you can define your callback function as per Microsoft's [Callback Function Implementation for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-implement-callback-functions) documentation.

NB: This is taken straight off Microsoft's Documentation as of today (2019-10-07) and will need to be reworked for your use case. This is just a function definition example:

```c#
using System;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
  
public delegate bool CallBack(int hwnd, int lParam);  
  
public class EnumReportApp  
{  
    [DllImport("user32")]  
    public static extern int EnumWindows(CallBack x, int y);   
  
    public static void Main()   
    {  
        CallBack myCallBack = new CallBack(EnumReportApp.Report);  
        EnumWindows(myCallBack, 0);  
    }  
  
    public static bool Report(int hwnd, int lParam)  
    {   
        Console.Write("Window handle is ");  
        Console.WriteLine(hwnd);  
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

Your callback function should make a return when the initially defined `revisions` has incremented, showing that the file has been saved.

#### References:

- [.NET Quickstart for Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Callback Function Implementation for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-implement-callback-functions)
- [Changes and Revisions overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/change-overview)
- [Revisions: list of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- [C# Google.Apis.Drive.v3.RevisionsResource.ListRequest Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1RevisionsResource_1_1ListRequest.html#a82e807deb7e4d6fd99c520bea156e18a)